# Angular model initialisation only work in post request

Tags: angularjs

My view :

```
...
<select ng-model="search.user" ng-options='user.id_user as (user.nom + " " + user.prenom) for user in users' ng-change="search()" class="form-control" name="categorie"></select>
...
<input type="text" ng-model="search.texte" ng-change="search()" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Rechercher...">
...
<select ng-model="search.offset" ng-options='offset for offset in offsetChoices' ng-change="search()" class="form-control" name="categorie"></select>
...
```

It works :

```
$scope.search={};

$http.post("/permission/get_users").success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
    $scope.users.unshift({id_user: 0, nom: "Tous les utilisateurs"});
    $scope.search.user = $scope.users[0].id_user;
    $scope.search.texte="";
    $scope.offsetChoices = [20, 30, 40, 50, 100];
    $scope.search.offset = $scope.offsetChoices[1];
});
```

It doesn't work :

```
$scope.search={};
$scope.search.texte="";
$scope.offsetChoices = [20, 30, 40, 50, 100];
$scope.search.offset = $scope.offsetChoices[1];

$http.post("/permission/get_users").success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
    $scope.users.unshift({id_user: 0, nom: "Tous les utilisateurs"});
    $scope.search.user = $scope.users[0].id_user;
});
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work outside of the post request.
Thanks !

Comment: What does not work outside POST request? I mean, what is not showing up in the view?

Comment: <select ng-model="search.offset" ng-options='offset for offset in offsetChoices' ng-change="search()" class="form-control" name="categorie"></select> isn't populate

Comment: `offsetChoices` is empty?